# JavaScript window.open() a page with loads of scripts on it - scripts shown like text

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, window.open

I am working on a legacy Classic ASP system. In there, there is a a bit of JavaScript that opens a certain `.asp` file via a pop-up with the use of JavaScript's `window.open()`.

The Classic ASP page that opens has in it a lot of JavaScript functions inside script tags. When this page is accessed via a URL, all is fine, the JavaScript is hidden like you would expect, but when I go to the same page via the `window.open()` route, I get something like this (note bottom edge):

[image: javascript printed as text]

As you can see, the javascript is all visible, when it should be hidden since it all sits in `<script>` tags.

The code calling the `window.open()` is as follows:

```html
<tr class='rowAlt' 
    height="15" 
    onClick="window.open(intranetPath+'/forms/<%=taskForm %>?taskReporting=true&uniqueId=<%=myRs("UNIQUE_ID")) %>', 
    'view_event', 
    'width=890, height=600, status=no, resizable=yes, scrollbars=1');" 
    onMouseOver="this.className='rowHighlighted'" 
    onMouseOut="this.className='rowAlt'">
```

Firefox and Chrome hide the script tags. It is only IE that is messing up!

How do I overcome this issue?

Comment: Down vote? :/ PS. When I add a `alert("boo!");` it works, I get the alert pop-up, so JavaScript can run, but why does it show? :(

Comment: Can you view the source code of your popup

Comment: Down-vote is likely because your question includes no source code, so it's difficult to imagine what the problem might be.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Tim. I have now gone ahead and added the code, also placed a note about FF and Chrome.

Comment: The issue is likely in the source for the opened page and not in the `window.open()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Tim Williams was correct. The page markup was messed up, it was a legacy system, and mu guess is that the person who coded it probably did not know what 'HTML Standards' were.

Thanks Tim.